# New Pooled Registered Pension Plan details?

Tags: canada, pension

Does anybody have a good summary / commentary on the new Pooled Registered Pension Plans recently passed by the Canadian gov't?

http://www.parl.gc.ca/HousePublications/Publication.aspx?Language=E&Mode=1&DocId=5697416

Is it only for self-employed or can anybody voluntarily contribute?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The general idea of the PRPP is so that small business who cannot afford to offer a plan alone will be able to pool resources with others along with self-employed to create voluntary, defined-contribution pension plans that would be managed by private sector financial institutions.

> The PRPP concept would offer more options to individuals as well  as
>   small and medium-sized businesses - [Tax Rules for Pooled Registered Pension Plans](http://www.chamber.ca/images/uploads/Reports/2011/Sub_PRPP%20Aug201108.pdf)

You can also find an overview here [THE NEW PRPP – A Pension for the Pension-Less](http://hrinsider.ca/homepage/the-new-prpp-a-pension-for-the-pension-less)